# Accessibility: Safari tab through skipping anchor tags without text

Tags: html, css, accessibility

*I have allowed tab through in safari's advanced settings

I am having an issue where Safari Tab through skips anchor tabs without text. The i class here is an icon. This works fine in firefox. I have tried a variety of things I found online such as adding name attributes and wrapping it in another anchor tag.

```
<a href="#" id="primary-search-clear-text" on-click="clear_search_for">
  <i class="close icon"><span class="accessible-text">{{clear_search_for_ada}}</span></i>
</a>
```

Comment: What's the rendered HTML and associated styles (icon is placed using `::before` pseudo element?)

Comment: Yeah exactly. It's a custom icon library with similar behavior to font awesome.